# Is Apps Script suitable for public service application?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, quota

I created a web app with apps script and spreadsheet.

And I'll start a business soon.

Does apps script cover these?:

1. The business will be used by over 10,000 per day;
2. It needs to cover 50 API call(at the same time);
3. 200 Concurrent connected Users.

If yes, How can I check the number of total users, api calls, concurrent connected users?

And at the moment, I use custom functions and and URLfetchs in other projects too. I am curious if the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) is counted per file or per google account or per group(G suite).

Comment: Quotas are per account. You should talk to the sales folks and explain your situation to see what they advise.

Comment: Concurrency will definitely be a issue.  As per your link, it's 30 (nowhere near 200)

Comment: If you want to stay within Google products for a Web App, you can look at Firebase Hosting or App Engine.